# Help with $\int \frac 1{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac 1{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} \,dx$$

In the second passage it become

$$\int \frac 1{a\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac xa\right)^2}}\,dx$$

So can someone explain me what kind operation is done at denominator?

Comment: yeah maybe i got a mistake with the syntax

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}\int \dfrac 1{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} \,\mathrm dx &= \dfrac 1{\sqrt{a^2\left(1 - \frac {x^2}{a^2}\right)}} \,\mathrm dx \\ \\ & = \int \dfrac 1{\sqrt {a^2}\cdot \sqrt{1 -\left(\frac xa\right)^2}} \,\mathrm dx \\ \\ & = \int \dfrac 1{|a|\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac xa\right)^2}}\,\mathrm dx\end{align}$$

If relevant to the transformation you are referring to, you might want to review the  [trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) $(\text{see: }\;x = a\sin \theta)$ for how this progresses, if needed.

Comment: You're welcome. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @amWhy: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ not $a$ unless $a\ge 0$

Comment: Substitution isn't the natural thing to do at the end, (at least not a trigonometric one). Recall that $(\arcsin\circ f)'(x)=f'(x)\cdot \arcsin '(f(x))=\dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-(f(x))^2}}$.

Comment: @GitGud I'm suggesting the reference because, given the OP's question about moving to the "second step", I'm assuming s/he is referencing an outline showing how the substitution for an integral in which $a^2 - x^2$ occurs can be solved by using the substitution $x = a\sin \theta$, that's all. The OP was not asking about how to integrate the integral, but how the move from the start proceeds to the next step in the transformation.

Comment: Thanks, @lab, for pointing out my oversight! I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @amWhy, my pleasure

Comment: Yes now it make sense :) thanks to all

Comment: Well hinted, though at the end we can write $$\frac1{|a|}\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xa\right)^2}}=\pm\int\frac{\left(\frac xa\right)'dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xa\right)^2}}=\pm\arcsin\frac xa+C$$ and the sign depends on the sign of $\;a\;$ . +1