# Integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$$

I had this question on my calc exam today, and I have no clue how it's done. I was trying to factor 4-x² to see if I could see any patterns but no luck.

One thing I did notice was that $$\frac{d}{dx}(\arcsin(x)) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

Comment: Write $\sqrt{4 - x^2} = 2\sqrt{1 - (x/2)^2}$ and make a variable change $t = x/2$.

Comment: What about substitution $x=2cos(\theta)$?

Comment: See [Help with $\int \frac 1{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} \mathrm dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596895/help-with-int-frac-1-sqrta2-x2-mathrm-dx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should note that whenever you have a formula, and it differs from your question by a constant (like here 4 instead of 1), then you can simply factor it out, obtaining $$
\int\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x/2)^2}}dx
$$
Then you can apply the formula that you found out, and it turns out that the substitution $$u=x/2$$ would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Your observation is apt.  Let $x = 2\sin u$ for the $u$-substitution, and then you obtain

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 - x^2}} dx \;\; =\;\; \int \frac{2\cos u}{2\sqrt{1 - \sin^2u}} du \;\; =\;\; u+ c
$$

where $c$ is constant.  We then get $u = \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{2}\right )$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=2\cos(\theta)$.

Note that $dx=-2\sin(\theta)d\theta$

Also use the fact that $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$

Comment: By $sen(\theta)$ do you mean $\sin(\theta)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm spanish speaker.